# Script to change gateway

Tags: powershell-3.0

I need a script to change gateway on multiple servers, if server(s) have an IP on specific subnet, change the gateway. Leave servers with no gateway alone.

I have a script below, when run, it will change the gateway on all servers listed on the text file whether server have gateway or not.

I think I need to have if and else statement on the script but I'm not good with scripting.

```psh
$DefGW = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

$vm_list = Get-Content "C:\Servers.txt"

foreach ($vm in $vm_list) {
  Write-Host ">>>>$vm<<<<" -Fore Red

  $nics = Get-WmiObject -Class Win_32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $vm -Filter "IPEnabled=True"

  foreach ($nic in $nics)
    if ($nic.ipaddress -match "xxx.xxx.") {
      $nic.SetGateways($DefGW)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the property [`DefaultIPGateway`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before calling `SetGateways()`. Something like this might work:

```psh
$DefGW = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'

Get-Content 'C:\Servers.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host ">>>>$_<<<<" -Fore Red

  Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer $_ -Filter 'IPEnabled=True' |
    Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -match 'xxx.xxx.' -and $_.DefaultIPGateway } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.SetGateways($DefGW) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ansgar. I did figure out using "if($nic.DefaultIPGateway -match "xxx.xxx.xxx") only to check for the gateway. Your solution is better so I took your yours :). May I ask you another question? I have separate script to ping the new gateway from the server for it to register the ARP table with the router before changing the gateway. I have a hard time trying to figure out how to have the script go through the server in the text file, ping the gateway from the server then change the gateway 1 server at a time. You have any suggestion?

Comment: Here is the script to ping the gateway from server:                                               "Get-Content "c:\Servers.txt"
    
    ForEach-Object
       {
       Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { cmd /c ping -n x xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx }
       }

Comment: @Nguyen Please do not move the target. If you have another question: post a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. I will post a separate post with the new question.